# Convergence in a norm vs convergence in a strong sense

Tags: functional-analysis, proof-verification, operator-theory, normed-spaces

Let $X = \text{BUC}(\mathbb{R})$ with supremum norm, where BUC is space of functions which are bounded and uniformly continuous.
Let's define an operator:
$$T_n: X \to X$$
$$T_n = f\bigg(x + \frac{1}{n} \bigg).$$
We are to prove that:
$$\lim_{n \to \infty} ||T_nf - f||_{\infty} = 0 \tag{1}$$
but
$$\lim_{n \to \infty} ||T_{n} - I||_{op} \neq 0 \tag{2},$$
where $||T||_{op}$ is the operator norm.

---

### My solution

#### Firstly let's prove $(1)$

Because $f \in X$ we can fix $\epsilon >0$ and find $\delta > 0$ such that:
$$\forall_{x,y \in \mathbb{R}} ||x-y||_{\infty} < \delta \implies ||f(x) - f(y)||_{\infty} < \epsilon.$$
Of course $$\forall{\delta>0} \exists_{N \in \mathbb{N}} \forall_{n>N} \bigg| \bigg|\frac{1}{n} \bigg| \bigg| < \delta.$$
Thus
$$\lim_{n \to \infty} \bigg| \bigg| f \bigg(x + \frac{1}{n} \bigg) - f(x) \bigg| \bigg|_{\infty} = \lim_{n \to \infty} \sup_{x \in \mathbb{R}} \bigg|f \bigg(x + \frac{1}{n} \bigg) - f(x) \bigg| = 0.$$

#### Now let's think about $(2)$

Let's define a sequence of functions: $g_n(x) = \sin(n \pi x)$.
It's obvious that $\forall_{n \in \mathbb{N}} g_n \in X$. Moreover $\forall_{n \in \mathbb{N}} ||g_n||_{\infty} = 1.$
$$||T_n - I||_{op} = \sup_{||f||_{\infty} = 1} ||T_nf - f||_{\infty} \tag{3}.$$
Because we do have the supremum norm over all $f \in X: ||f||_{\infty} = 1$ thus $(3)$ has to be equal or bigger than the following one:
$$||T_ng_n - g_n||_{\infty} = \sup_{x \in \mathbb{R}} |-2 \sin(n \pi x)| = 2.$$
In conclusion
$$\lim_{n \to \infty} ||T_n - I||_{op} \ge 2 \not\to 0.$$
I wonder if my attempts are correct?
If they are I would like to ask why the sequence $g_n$ works in $(2)$ but doesn't in $(1)$? I know that the two norms are something different but honestly I can't see any difference in the calculations. I mean that putting $g_n$ into $(1)$ would lead to something very similar. Where's the difference?

Comment: I don't understand "BUC is the space of functions which are bounded and uniformly convergent". If you have any norm on $\mathbb{R}$ (which must have the form $\lVert x \rVert = c\lvert x \rvert$ with some $c > 0$), then the supremum norm on the set $B(\mathbb{R})$ of bounded continuous functions $f :  \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$ yields nothing else than the topology of uniform convergence. It is not a property of a function that is  uniformly convergent. Or do you mean $BUC(\mathbb{R}) = (B(\mathbb{R}), \lVert . \rVert_\infty)$?

Comment: Do you mean $BUC(\mathbb R)$ is the space of all bounded and uniformly *continuous* functions $f:\mathbb R\to\mathbb R$ (or $\mathbb C$)?

Comment: I think you mean uniformly continuous, not uniformly convergent, since usually I see the space of bounded functions with the uniform convergence norm (that is, the supremum norm) as $L^\infty(\mathbb{R})$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If by $BUC(\mathbb R)$ you mean the space of bounded and uniformly *continuous* functions $f:\mathbb R\to\mathbb R$ (or $\mathbb R\to\mathbb C$, whichever you prefer), then the proofs are correct.

I think your confusion comes from the distinction between strong convergence and norm convergence of operators.  Think of strong convergence of operators as similar to pointwise convergence of functions from introductory real analysis, and norm convergence of operators as similar to uniform convergence of functions.  In pointwise convergence (resp. strong convergence), rates of convergence can vary wildly from point to point (resp. function to function), while in uniform convergence (resp. norm convergence),  points (resp. functions) must tend to the limit in a uniform manner.

Comment: Thanks for your explanation. I still don't understand why the sequence $g_n(x) = \sin(n \pi x)$ doesn't work in proving $(1)$?

Comment: I'm sorry, could you clarify?  $(1)$ says that $T_nf$ converges to $f$ for each $f\in BUC$, and this is also true for $f=g_n$, but it is not sufficient to prove it for only the functions $g_n$.

Comment: I'm sorry, you're right that it might have been a bit uncleared. We can't use $g_n$ as a counter example in proving $(1)$ because our calculation are based on the fact that we're doing it for a fixed function from $BUC$, aren't they? In $(2)$ however we look what is happening with a sequence of functions?

Comment: For the first question, yes.  For the second question, almost.  Norm convergence requires uniform convergence on the unit ball of $BUC$, so finding a sequence in the unit ball that behaves badly is enough.

Comment: Thank you! I needed some time to get used to this but now I think I finally get the point :)